# npm install shows command for module installed, but no new files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I added rx-angular to my npm package, and when I installed it locally, it grabbed the dependency for rx without any problem. When I went to release to production, it seems to sort of work, but not completely, which confused me (error wise), forcing me to install rx manually. Obviously, one package isn't a big deal, but this doesn't seem to be the correct behavior, and I'm not sure if I'm setting up my package improperly, or some other bug I need to resolve.

Here was the output of `npm install` on production:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rx-angular
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rx-angular
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rx-angular/-/rx-angular-1.1.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rx-angular/-/rx-angular-1.1.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rx
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rx
rx-angular@1.1.3 node_modules/rx-angular
â””â”€â”€ rx@4.1.0
```

As you can see, rx was grabbed, but then something funked up on it's install I think? Thus the funky characters? I donno, I'm not sure what went wrong, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I don't have rx in my package, just rx-angular, as I try on rx-angular to knw what version of rx it needs to function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
npm cache clean
```

If not, try to remove manually installed modules

```
rm -R node_modules/
```

and then

```
npm install
```

Comment: Ah, you think it's a cache issue?

Comment: So updating node plus this seems to have worked, though now ALL the modules are preceeded by the funky `â””â”€â”` characters, in some variation or another (and it's now installed a TON more modules, which I guess is from the update?).

Comment: Probably you are running an old version of npm (and node?). Update it with `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: I'm at 6.9.1 now; the update is what caused all the funky characters.

Comment: @RhoVisions npm version?

Comment: I said just above, 6.9.1

Comment: that's node version not npm

Comment: @RhoVisions have you tried `npm install npm@latest -g`?